# CDK: How to access Manual action properties and use it as variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a manual action configured for codepipeline using CDK.

```
const manualApprovalAction = new codepipeline_actions.ManualApprovalAction({
      actionName: 'Approval',
      notificationTopic: topic,
      additionalInformation: 'some value',
      externalEntityLink: 'abc'
    })
```

Is there a way to access the property `externalEntityLink` as variable? In other words, do manual approval actions expose action properties? I couldn't find any supporting document related to that.

for example ( just for the reference)

```
const externalEntityLinkvar = manualApprovalAction.something.externalEntityLink
```

Comment: Why cant you just set the `externalEntityLink` as a variable and pass that in? So you have it within scope? Failing that the `props` are attached to the class but are `private` - could get around that using `manualApprovalAction['props'].externalEntityLink` I believe

Comment: I could do that but my original question is that do manual approval actions exposes it as a property or can we access it like property?